# 'base/debug/debugging_buildflags.h' file not found when building project with webrtc

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake, webrtc

I am building a project that includes webrtc with CMake, Visual Studio 2019 and ClangCl. This is the command I run to configure :

> cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DDEPOT_TOOLS_PATH="C:\dev\depot_tools" -T ClangCl -S . -B debug-x86

and to build :

> cmake --build debug-x86 --parallel --config Debug --target

The cmake script runs this command at config:

> gn.bat gen /path/to/project/debug-x86/vendor/webrtc/Debug --args=  use_gold=false   target_cpu="x86"   target_os="win"   rtc_build_examples=false   rtc_initialize_ffmpeg=false   rtc_build_tools=false   rtc_use_h264=false   is_component_build=false   rtc_enable_protobuf=false   clang_use_chrome_plugins=false   use_custom_libcxx_for_host=false   treat_warnings_as_errors=false   use_sysroot=false   enable_location_source=false   is_official_build=false   use_rtti=true use_custom_libcxx=false rtc_include_tests=false is_debug=true symbol_level=2 enable_iterator_debugging=true

and runs this command at build before building the main project:

> C:/Dev/depot_tools/ninja.exe  -C path/to/project/debug-x86/vendor/webrtc/Debug webrtc system_wrappers builtin_audio_decoder_factory libjingle_peerconnection

My problem is that when building the main project i receive this error :
`vendor\webrtc\src\base/dcheck_is_on.h(8,10): fatal error : 'base/debug/debugging_buildflags.h' file not found`

My understanding is that this file is supposed to be generated by `webertc/src/base/BUILD.gn`. Am I missing an argument to trigger the generation? Why is this header not being generated? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include also `chromium\src\out\[your_build_dir]\gen` directory

There is where all *buildflags.h are generated after building your chromium module